# dropdown select-box with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, drop-down-menu

I want to create an online shop with laravel. I want to show category and subcategory with dropdown select in jquery.(my data fetch from database).
Can every one help me. thank you.

Comment: Can **you** help us by showing what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [tutorial](https://www.codechief.org/article/hierarchical-treeview-category-example-in-laravel). It has nicely described about adding category and sub categoies for an online shop using laravel.

Apart from that I suggest adding categories and subcategories to the same table with parent child relationship.